# MySQL Insert restriction

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to restrict inserts by a subquery or something like else without having the same data in different columns of different tables?
My example, I have the following tables:

**Products**
- ProductID
- CompanyID
- ProductDescription

**User**
- UserID
- CompanyID
- UserDescription

**Orders**
- OrderID
- Date
- UserID
- ProductID


Each user belongs to a company, each product is made by a company and every company may order products of each other. The catch: a company may order a product only once per day.

So I would love to make a constrain in **Orders** to make the combination of *Date*, *ProductID* and *User.CompanyID*. Then I could just do the insert statement and catch the exception or use "insert ignore" to just avoid invalid data. This is just a simplified case. I often have this problem where I would love to create a constrain with a column of a referenced table without using a bunch of triggers.

Is that possible in any way or am I forced to do a select first, check the result and then do the inserts if everything is valid?

Comment: Do you want some sort of unique constraint?  I don't understand why `User.CompanyID` is being lumped together with other columns from the `Orders` table.

Comment: You could do a `before insert trigger` that throws an error if the conditions are not met.

Comment: @juergend: It seems OP does not want use trigger. _... without using a bunch of triggers ..._

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to force all entries in **Orders** to be unique by *Date*, *ProductID* and *User.CompanyID WHERE User.UserID = Orders.UserID*. So when there is an entry with *ProductID* = 2, *Date* = '2017-12-01' and *UserID* = 9, another entry with the same product, same date and another user from the same company may not exist in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it like this:
1. Add an `CompanyID` column in table `Orders`;
2. Create an unique index which is a combination of (`CompanyID`,`Date`,`ProductID`).

The point here is: using the Unique Constraint to prevent a company from ordering the same product on the same day.

If you don't want any redundant data, you may apply a transaction. Just something like this:

```
BEGIN;
IF 
  (SELECT CompanyID FROM User WHERE UserID = userid LOCK IN SHARE MODE) 
NOT IN 
  (SELECT CompanyID FROM User WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Orders WHERE Date = date AND ProductID = productid LOCK IN SHARE MODE) LOCK IN SHARE MODE) 
THEN
    INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (...);
END IF;
COMMIT;
```

As you can see, the code above is ugly, and it must be a performance killer.
There isn't any information about company in your `Orders` table. If you want to satisfy your weird demand, you must pay, and that is the price.

In my opinion, a redundant `CompanyID` column is just fine. It makes everything much faster and easier. Systems those who want to run faster usually hold redundant data.

Comment: Really hoped I could do that without breaking the normalization of the database or without using ugly triggers. Seems like I have to decide between clean, simple code or a normalized database :/